# 'CreateDirectoryW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char *' to 'LPCWSTR' in OpenCV 2.4.5 and VS 2010

Tags: c++, opencv, classification, sample

I was trying the sample code bagofwords_classification.cpp from openCV 2.4.5 to Visual Studio 2010 (VC++ based). But I found the error code :

```
error C2664: 'CreateDirectoryW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char *' to 'LPCWSTR'
```

Can you help me to give me the solution about that problem? Thanks. :)

**Update v1:**

```
static void makeDir( const string& dir )
{
#if defined WIN32 || defined _WIN32
    CreateDirectory( dir.c_str(), 0 );
#else
    mkdir( dir.c_str(), S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH );
#endif
}

static void makeUsedDirs( const string& rootPath )
{
    makeDir(rootPath + bowImageDescriptorsDir);
    makeDir(rootPath + svmsDir);
    makeDir(rootPath + plotsDir);
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you passing in? It's probably easy enough to make it a wide string from the start.

Comment: I don't have anytthing to pass in. I just copy and paste that code bagofwords_classification.cpp and execute it. I don't know how to execute that code well.

Comment: You must if it's complaining about something you passed in (the first thing).

Comment: I've attach the error code. Would you tell me how to pass in? I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have code that calls `CreateDirectory`. When `UNICODE` is defined, that symbol is actually a macro for `CreateDirectoryW`; the intention is for you to use "ambiguous" function names when you're also using `TCHAR` instead of `char` or `wchar_t`, so you can switch between compiling for Unicode or Ansi programs.

However, `std::string` doesn't change according to `UNICODE`; it's *always* Ansi, so its `c_str` method always returns a `char*`, never `wchar_t*`. When you have a parameter that's always Ansi, you should explicitly call functions that are always Ansi, too. In this case, call `CreateDirectoryA`.

You could also consider using `std::basic_string<TCHAR>`, but that's probably heading in a direction you don't wish to go.

A quick fix would be to adjust your project settings so that `UNICODE` is no longer defined. Consult the documentation for your tool set to find out how to do that, or explore your IDE's project options.

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2010 as my IDE. How can I do a quick fix? It seems as the good solution, but I still can't solve.

Comment: I don't use Visual Studio, so you're at an advantage over me in being able to do as I suggested and explore the options available in the dialog. Searching Google yielded a question here on Stack Overflow, too: [How do I turn off Unicode in a VC++ project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319461/how-do-i-turn-off-unicode-in-a-vc-project) Sounds promising.

Answer (score 5):

`CreateDirectory` will be defined as `CreateDirectoryW` which expects its parameters to be "wide" strings (UTF-16 encoded `WCHAR*`).

To create a wide string you can prepend `L` to a regular string.

```
CreateDirectory(L"mydir", NULL);
```

Alternatively, you can switch your project to multibyte encoding in the properties. This will mean that calling `CreateDirectory` will automatically use the `CreateDirectoryA` version of the function which accepts `char*` strings. These are expected to be in the multibyte encoding of the active codepage.

Comment: I must change CreateDirectory(...) into CreateDirectoryW(...), mustn't I?

Comment: No, `CreateDirectoryW` is currently being called and that's where your problem lies. You are passing the wrong type of argument. You could explicitly call `CreateDirectoryA` which will allow you to pass a `char*`. However, if you intend to use a lot of Windows API functions with `char*` as opposed to `WCHAR*` you'd be better off changing the encoding of the project.

Comment: I don't have argument to be passed in. 
I am trying to learn the bagofwords_classification.cpp code and I will tell how to use that code if I execute that code successfully.

Answer (score 3):

CreateDirectoryW accepts wide char, if you are using Unicode mode it is ok. You probably should use CreateDirectory or CreateDirectoryA.

Comment: I will try this solution if I know how to use this. Thanks, @Giswin