# C2664 error, C++ which is foreign to me

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

The error I  get is:

`"DWORD GetModuleFileNameW(HMODULE,LPWSTR,DWORD)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char *' to 'LPWSTR"`

On this line

```
GetModuleFileName(NULL, &strL[0], MAX_PATH);
```

This the code

```
    BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        {
            std::string strL;
            strL.resize(MAX_PATH);
            GetModuleFileName(NULL, &strL[0], MAX_PATH);

            DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hModule);

            if(strL.find("notepad.exe") != std::string::npos)
            {
                gl_hThisInstance = hModule;

                LoadOriginalDll();
            }

            break;
        }
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        {
            ExitInstance();

            break;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: We need more of your code. In particular, the definition of `strL` (although we *know* what it is, because the error message describes it in sufficient detail).

Comment: and please use correct formatting. unformatted code makes it hard to read

Comment: `typedef wchar_t* LPWSTR, *PWSTR; `

Comment: You enabled wide characters (i.e. Unicode) but your string is a regular (non-wide) `char*`. Use a wide string instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230355.aspx),

```
typedef wchar_t* LPWSTR, *PWSTR;
```

So it is expecting a `wchar_t *` (wchar_t is 2 bytes or more), but `&std::string[0]` is a `char*` (char is a byte). You need to use `std::wstring` instead:

```
std::wstring strL;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to compile without using wide strings, refer to here:

[How do I turn off Unicode in a VC++ project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319461/how-do-i-turn-off-unicode-in-a-vc-project)

Chances are if Unicode is enabled in VC++, there are defines like this:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define CreateFile  CreateFileW
#else
#define CreateFile  CreateFileA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

Fix:

> Have you tried: Project Properties - General - Project Defaults -
>   Character Set?
>
> See answers in this question for the differences between "Use
>   Multi-Byte Character Set" and "Not Set" options: About the "Character
>   set" option in visual studio 2010

And from the link inside the quote:

> It is a compatibility setting, intended for legacy code that was
>   written for old versions of Windows that were not Unicode enabled.
>   Versions in the Windows 9x family, Windows ME was the last one. With
>   "Not Set" or "Use Multi-Byte Character Set" selected, all Windows API
>   functions that take a string as an argument are redefined to a little
>   compatibility helper function that translates char* strings to
>   wchar_t* strings, the API's native string type.

Comment: I deleted the complete bool because it's conflicting with the project >.< MSDN was correct and this answer is also correct