# Wrong print out of binary file using _tprintf

Tags: c, windows, winapi, binaryfiles, tchar

I must read a binary file, but I have wrong output. I start from a txt file that contains:

```
1 100000 Romano Antonio 1250
2 150000 Fabrizi Aldo 2245
3 200000 Verdi Giacomo 11115
4 250000 Rossi Luigi 13630
```

I generate the relative binary file by with program:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1000

/*
 *  Problem1: use tchar.h and _tmain instead of
 *  int main (int argc, LPTSTR argv [])
 *  Sometimes it is needeed to see argv correctly
 */
int _tmain (int argc, LPTSTR argv [])
{
  HANDLE hIn, hOut;
  DWORD nIn, nOut;
  CHAR buffer [BUF_SIZE];

  if (argc != 3) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Usage: cp file1 file2\n");
    return 1;
  }

  hIn = CreateFile (argv[1], GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL); /*Here hIn is created with read access*/
  if (hIn == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    fprintf (stderr,
      "Cannot open input file. Error: %x\n", GetLastError ());
    return 2;
  }

  hOut = CreateFile (argv[2], GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
    CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
  if (hOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    fprintf (stderr,
      "Cannot open output file. Error: %x\n", GetLastError ());
    CloseHandle(hIn);
    return 3;
  }

  while (ReadFile (hIn, buffer, BUF_SIZE, &nIn, NULL) && nIn > 0) {
/*hIn is the handle to the read file, buffer is a pointer to the buffer that receives the data read 
from the file, BUF_SIZE is the maximum number of bytes to be read, &nIn is 
the pointer to the variable that receives the n° of bytes read*/
    /*
     *  Problem 2:
     *  During the last cycle less than BUF_SIZE characters may
     *  be read from file
     *  WriteFile (hOut, buffer, BUF_SIZE, &nOut, NULL);
     *  so write just the number of characters read
     */
    WriteFile (hOut, buffer, nIn, &nOut, NULL); /*I write in file related hOut, the content of read file hIn is in buffer, 
nIn is the n° of bytes to write, &nOut is a pointer to the variable that receives the number of bytes written*/
    if (nIn != nOut) {
      fprintf (stderr, "Fatal write error: %x\n", GetLastError ());
      CloseHandle(hIn); CloseHandle(hOut);
      return 4;
    }
  }

  CloseHandle (hIn);
  CloseHandle (hOut);
  return 0;
}
```

Now I think that it gives me a binary file. Then, I have to read this binary file and put the data into a struct. My code is:

```
#if 1
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define L 30+1
#define SETFILEPOINTER_OVERLAPPING 1
#define N 3
#define BUF_SIZE 1000

struct myacc {
    int id;
    long int acc_number;
    TCHAR surname[L];
    TCHAR name[L];
    int amount;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HANDLE hIn;
    OVERLAPPED ov = {0, 0, 0, 0, NULL};
    DWORD nIn,n;
    //TCHAR c;
    //TCHAR buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    LARGE_INTEGER filePos;
    struct myacc account;

    if(argc != N) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error into arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }

    hIn = CreateFile(argv[1], GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hIn == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            fprintf (stderr,"Cannot open input file. Error: %x\n", GetLastError ());
            return 2;
        }

    n=1;
    filePos.QuadPart = (n-1) * sizeof(struct myacc);

#if SETFILEPOINTER_OVERLAPPING
    SetFilePointerEx (hIn, filePos, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
    while(ReadFile (hIn, &account, sizeof (struct myacc), &nIn, NULL) && nIn > 0) {
        _tprintf (_T("-> %d %ld %s %s %d <-\n"), account.id, account.acc_number, account.surname, account.name, account.amount);
    }
#else
    ov.Offset = filePos.LowPart; /*Uso l'overlapped structure ov se ho asynchronous I/O*/
    ov.OffsetHigh = filePos.HighPart;
    while(ReadFile (hIn, &account, sizeof (struct myacc), &nIn, &ov) && nIn > 0) {
        _tprintf (_T("-> %d %ld %s %s %d <-\n"), account.id, account.acc_number, account.surname, account.name, account.amount);
    }
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Now, in this part of code

```
while(ReadFile (hIn, &account, sizeof (struct myacc), &nIn, NULL) && nIn > 0) {
            _tprintf (_T("-> %d %ld %s %s %d <-\n"), account.id, account.acc_number, account.surname, account.name, account.amount);
        }
```

the output is wrong, that is:
[image]

Why do I get this? I generate wrong bin file? Or I manage bad the output function? I hope you can help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're literally duplicating your text file. You're entire first program could have been written with a single win32 api call, [CopyFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Just because you replicated the file doesn't magically transform it into the structured layout you seem to be expecting with your second code. It seems to me your *first* program should be reading text, *translating* it into the structured layout you want, then writing *that*.

Comment: As you were told in the [other discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269383/), your input file is NOT A BINARY FILE, it is a TEXT FILE.  It DOES NOT contain binary structures in it, so stop trying to read it as if it did. Read it as a text file. Use the standard `std::ifstream` class to open it, then you can use things like `operator>>`, or `std::getline()` and `std::istringstream`, to read and parse the text as needed. Reading the raw bytes of the original file and writing them as-is to another file does not automatically create a binary file.  You have to CONVERT the data.

Comment: you might want to look as this answer: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319461/how-do-i-turn-off-unicode-in-a-vc-project> in regards to using plain text or using unicode.   Have you examined the produced file to see what its' actual contents are?

Answer (score 1):

You believe that *second program* is wrong, but we don't know if it is wrong because the *input* for the second program is also wrong.

Input for the second program (also output of the first program) is supposed to be a binary file, but it is actually a text file, identical to the the input of the first program. It is identical because the first program is not making any kind of conversion. All it does is `ReadFile(..., buffer, ..., &nIn, ...)` immediately followed by `WriteFile(..., buffer, nIn, ...)`. These two lines just copy all the data.

First program should use `getline()` (like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868998/395718), in a second method, line-based parsing) instead of `ReadFile()`, get all the data, populate one `struct myacc` object, and `WriteFile` contents of that object.