# MSDN Example: The Open Dialog Box Not Compiling

Tags: c++, msdn

Getting errors when trying to compile sample code:

[MSDN Example: The Open Dialog Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485843(v=vs.85).aspx)

Why?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shobjidl.h> 

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED |
        COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        IFileOpenDialog *pFileOpen;

        // Create the FileOpenDialog object.
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL,
            IID_IFileOpenDialog, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pFileOpen));

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Show the Open dialog box.
            hr = pFileOpen->Show(NULL);

            // Get the file name from the dialog box.
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                IShellItem *pItem;
                hr = pFileOpen->GetResult(&pItem);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    PWSTR pszFilePath;
                    hr = pItem->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &pszFilePath);

                    // Display the file name to the user.
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        MessageBox(NULL, pszFilePath, L"File Path", MB_OK);
                        CoTaskMemFree(pszFilePath);
                    }
                    pItem->Release();
                }
            }
            pFileOpen->Release();
        }
        CoUninitialize();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> Error C2664   'int MessageBoxA(HWND,LPCSTR,LPCSTR,UINT)': cannot convert
>   argument 2 from 'PWSTR' to 'LPCSTR'   MSDNTut_3-OpenFileDialogBox
>   ...\msdntut_3-openfiledialogbox\msdntut_3-openfiledialogbox\source.cpp    34
>
> Error (active)    E0167   argument of type "const wchar_t *" is
>   incompatible with parameter of type
>   "LPCSTR"  MSDNTut_3-OpenFileDialogBox ...\MSDNTut_3-OpenFileDialogBox\MSDNTut_3-OpenFileDialogBox\Source.cpp  34
>
> Error (active)    E0167   argument of type "PWSTR" is incompatible with
>   parameter of type
>   "LPCSTR"  MSDNTut_3-OpenFileDialogBox ...\MSDNTut_3-OpenFileDialogBox\MSDNTut_3-OpenFileDialogBox\Source.cpp  34

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 
Version 15.7.1
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.7.1+27703.2000
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.02556

Installed Version: Community

> I fixed it by adding
>
> ```
> #ifndef UNICODE
> #define UNICODE
> #endif
> ```
>
> to the top.. I would still like an explanation on why that was necessary, please. ;)

Another fix is to Set the "Character Set" to "Use Unicode Character Set"

Project-> (Project Name) Properties->General->Project Defaults->Character Set

Comment: You must have turned UNICODE off when creating your project.

Comment: Turned it off? I don't even know where to find any toggle options.

Comment: @JwGaming See [How do I turn off Unicode in a VC++ project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319461/)

Comment: @RemyLebeau I had looked at it and I was finally able to find it now.

Project-> (Project Name) Properties->General->Project Defaults->Character Set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I fixed it by adding
>
> ```
> #ifndef UNICODE
> #define UNICODE
> #endif
> ```
>
> to the top..
>   I would still like an explanation on why that was necessary, please. ;)

`MessageBox` is not actually a function, it is a macro:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define MessageBox  MessageBoxW
#else
#define MessageBox  MessageBoxA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

So, depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined, `MessageBox()` maps to either `MessageBoxW()` (Unicode) or `MessageBoxA()` (ANSI).  Your project is not defining `UNICODE`, so `MessageBoxA()` gets used, and `PWSTR` (pointer to wide string) is not compatible with `LPCSTR` (pointer to narrow string).

You could have used `PSTR` instead, or enabled UNICODE support, as you did.

Comment: Thanks for answering and editing my Question. I was having a hard time getting the format right and it looks much better.

I didn't know that (about the macro). I will keep that in mind for the future. I have just been adding the Unicode support by habit from the first module of the MSDN.

Comment: @JwGaming MS is using quite a few macros for these purposes, but you can always check it by `right click on the name->Peek Definition`

Comment: "*You could have used `PSTR` instead*" - that would have required more coding, as `IShellItem::GetDisplayName()` outputs only `PWSTR` data, so to use `MessageBox(A)` with `PSTR`, you would have to convert the data using `WideCharToMultiByte()` or equivalent.

Comment: @RemyLebeau >  solution would be to change MessageBox() to MessageBoxW() <   I also like this solution you proposed.